# Dropdown selected="selected" issue

Tags: php

I'm building an school script in PHP. My php code snippet is like this:

```
$sid = intval($mybb->input['sid']);
$query = $db->simple_select("student_list", "*", "sid='{$sid}'");
$s = $db->fetch_array($query);

$class_selected = '';
if ($s['student_class'] == $mybb->input['student_class'])
{
    $class_selected = ' selected="selected"';
}
```

and HTML is like this:

```
<select name="student_class" class="textbox" tabindex="2">
    <option value="Play Group"'.$class_selected.'>Play Group</option>
    <option value="Nursery"'.$class_selected.'>Nursery</option>
    <option value="Prep."'.$class_selected.'>Prep.</option>
    <option value="1"'.$class_selected.'>One</option>
    <option value="2"'.$class_selected.'>Two</option>
    <option value="3"'.$class_selected.'>Three</option>
    <option value="4"'.$class_selected.'>Four</option>
    <option value="5"'.$class_selected.'>Five</option>
    <option value="6"'.$class_selected.'>Six</option>
    <option value="7"'.$class_selected.'>Seven</option>
    <option value="8"'.$class_selected.'>Eight</option>
    <option value="9"'.$class_selected.'>Nine</option>
    <option value="10"'.$class_selected.'>Ten</option>
</select>
```

But unfortunately upon running the script the value is not selected at all. :/

By the way the value of `$s['student_class']` is `Nursery`

Please help.

Comment: Didn't you forget `echo`?

Comment: Place `<?php echo $class_selected; ?>`   instead of  $class_selected

Comment: @u_mulder: Nope, the page is running the PHP code, it just don't show the selected="selected"

Comment: Then please open generated html and see what you have there. And I repeat - didn't you forget `echo`?

Comment: @ImranOmer Or do you want to say that shown html is acutally wrapped in `echo '<select....>';`? If not, you forgot to `echo`.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, the shown HTML is already wrapped in `echo`

Comment: then your logic is wrong. You'll have to compare each option and overwrite $class_selected. Now you have multiple times an selected option, which doesn't work. Or is there some more code you didn't show?? Like a while? (which you would need)

Comment: I suggest using a ternary operator for this instead. I've had unexpected results in the past using logic as yours.

Comment: If your value in db is `nursery` as opposed to `Nursery`, then that could be another problem.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Can you please show me some sample code? or how could I work around using ternary operator? I am beginner in PHP. Thanks

Comment: If you view your HTML source, you will see that all are "selected". Only the "last" value is shown as being selected. Again; use a ternary operator.

Comment: Maybe you don't read all the comments. @u_mulder pointed you to this issue: You are passing a `php` variable between `html` so you need to echo this vars: <?php echo $class_selected; ?>

Comment: @Franco Now you didn't read all the comments... Imran already said, that the whole html-block is wrapped in `echo '<select...>';`

Comment: Let the guy update his code then. It will be much easier don't you think? :) I thing that we also have to guess of this php code is on the same peage where the `html` is of is included in some way?

Comment: @ImranOmer I was away for a bit. I posted an example for you in the answers area.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in comments, it's best to use a ternary operator for things like this.

- They're a bit trickier inside an echo, but well worth the effort.

Assuming a successful query and that:

```
if ($s['student_class'] == $mybb->input['student_class'])
```

and the above is equal to one of the options below and remember that strings are case-sensitive, the following will work:

**Sidenote:** You mentioned in comments that the code was inside an echo.

```
$class_selected = 'Nursery'; // Assumed input

echo '
<select name="student_class" class="textbox" tabindex="2">

    <option value="Play Group" '.(($class_selected == 'Play Group') ? "selected" : "").'>Play Group</option>

    <option value="Nursery" '.(($class_selected == 'Nursery') ? "selected" : "").'>Nursery</option>

    <option value="" '.(($class_selected == 'Prep.') ? "selected" : "").'>Prep.</option>

    <option value="1" '.(($class_selected == '1') ? "selected" : "").'>One</option>

    <option value="2" '.(($class_selected == '2') ? "selected" : "").'>Two</option>

    <option value="3" '.(($class_selected == '3') ? "selected" : "").'>Three</option>

    <option value="4" '.(($class_selected == '4') ? "selected" : "").'>Four</option>

    <option value="5" '.(($class_selected == '5') ? "selected" : "").'>Five</option>

    <option value="6" '.(($class_selected == '6') ? "selected" : "").'>Six</option>

    <option value="7" '.(($class_selected == '7') ? "selected" : "").'>Seven</option>

    <option value="8" '.(($class_selected == '8') ? "selected" : "").'>Eight</option>

    <option value="9" '.(($class_selected == '9') ? "selected" : "").'>Nine</option>

    <option value="10" '.(($class_selected == '10') ? "selected" : "").'>Ten</option>

</select>

';
```